# WinForms transparent picture box not working

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have been trying to lay an image in black/gray over a background, and I would like the background to show through on the transparent sections of the image. The image is definitely saved as a transparent png correctly. What is wrong with the code below?

```
this.pictureBox14.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
this.pictureBox14.BackgroundImage = ((System.Drawing.Image)(resources.GetObject("pictureBox14.BackgroundImage")));
this.pictureBox14.BackgroundImageLayout = System.Windows.Forms.ImageLayout.None;
this.pictureBox14.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Hand;
this.pictureBox14.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(486, 337);
this.pictureBox14.Name = "pictureBox14";
this.pictureBox14.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(69, 62);
this.pictureBox14.SizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode.CenterImage;
this.pictureBox14.TabIndex = 18;
this.pictureBox14.TabStop = false;
this.pictureBox14.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.pictureBox14_Click);
```

Comment: what is the color on the image that needs to be transparent?

Comment: post a photo at runtime?

Comment: I found the solution is doing this.pictureboxX.parent = this.parentPictureBox

Here is a handy python script if you want to do it for all picture boxes in a range 3-25 : ([print("this.pictureBox" + str(x) + ".Parent = this.pictureBox2;") for x in range(3,25)])

Comment: @SwimBikeRun Please post your own solution as an answer and mark it as accepted